# Multiple recompositions are triggered while using collectAsStateWithLifecycle() method in a composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a Component activity with a NavHost which has 2 composables representing 2 screens. In the first screen composable, I collect a counter value which is a stateflow present in the viewModel that holds the count value. In the second screen, I increment the counter value in the viewmodel based on an API call success. The API call is triggered from a button click & after success, I increment the counter & pop the backstack going back to the first screen to show the incremented counter value. A ViewModel is shared between the two composable screens.

Two ways to collect a stateflow present in the viewmodel in a composable function are

1. viewModel.apiStatus.collectAsState()
2. viewModel.apiStatus.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

I understand that the latter is the recommended way as its lifecycle aware.
But when I collect the apiStatus using collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
and try to pop backstack to go to the first screen, the second screen is recomposing over & over again and collecting the values multiple times and incrementing the counter more than once i.e. the **handleResponse()** method is called multiple times.

Any help in identifying why this **side effect** is happening & how to solve this issue will be really helpful in my understanding of compose.

Sample Code

```
//called from setContent{} in MainActivity

@Composable
fun SampleNavSetup(sampleViewModel: SampleViewModel) {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController,
        startDestination = SampleNav.FirstPage.route) {

       this.composable(route = SampleNav.FirstPage.route) {
           FirstPageScreen(
               viewModel = sampleViewModel,
               navHostController = navController
           )
        }

        this.composable(route = SampleNav.SecondPage.route){
           SecondPageScreen(
               viewModel = sampleViewModel,
               navHostController = navController
           )
        }
    }
 }

 @Composable
 fun FirstPageScreen(
     viewModel: SampleViewModel,
     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
     navHostController: NavHostController
  ) {
   Column(
       modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(24.dp),
       horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
   ) {

      val result = viewModel.getIncrementCounter().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

      Text(
        fontSize = 18.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
        text = "Counter value is = ${result.value}"
      )

      Button(
         modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 36.dp),
         onClick = {
            navHostController.navigate(SampleNav.SecondPage.route)
          }
      ) {
        Text(
            text = "Nav to next",
            color = Color.White
        )
      }
    }
 }

@Composable
fun SecondPageScreen(
   viewModel: SampleViewModel,
   navHostController: NavHostController) {

   Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

       HandleApiResponse(
           modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 96.dp).align(Alignment.Center),
           viewModel = viewModel,
           navHostController = navHostController
       )

       Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp).align(Alignment.TopCenter),
           horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
       ) {

           Text(
               fontSize = 18.sp,
               fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
               text = "Make Fake API to increment counter"
           )

           Button(
               modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 36.dp),
               onClick = {
                  viewModel.doFakeApiCall()
               }
           ) {
               Text(
                  text = "Click Me",
                  color = Color.White
               )
           }
        }
     }
  }


 @Composable
 fun HandleApiResponse(
     modifier: Modifier,
     viewModel: SampleViewModel,
     navHostController: NavHostController
  ) {

    Log.d("Collect Second Page","Collect Handle Api response composable function")
    val context = LocalContext.current

    //does not trigger multiple times with collectAsState()
    //val response = viewModel.getApiStatus().collectAsState()

    /*But with collectAsStateWithLifeCycle() it is observed multiple
     times as the screen is recomposed multiple times & handleResponse is called 
     multiple times, don't know the reason why*/
 
    val response = viewModel.getApiStatus().collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    when (response.value) {

    FakeApiState.Loading -> {
        CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = modifier.size(32.dp),
        color = Color.Green)
    }

    FakeApiState.Success -> {
        Log.d("Collect Second Page","Collect Api status")
        handleResponse(viewModel = viewModel,navHostController=navHostController)
     }

      FakeApiState.Fail -> {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Api Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }

      FakeApiState.Initial -> {}
   }
}

private fun handleResponse(
    viewModel: SampleViewModel,
    navHostController: NavHostController
) {
    Log.d("Second Page Response", "Collect Handle Response & popBackStack()")
    viewModel.incrementCounter()
    navHostController.popBackStack()
    viewModel.clearApiStatus()
 }


class SampleViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _incrementCounter = MutableStateFlow(0)
    fun getIncrementCounter() = _incrementCounter.asStateFlow()

    private val _apiStatus = MutableStateFlow(FakeApiState.Initial)
    fun getApiStatus() = _apiStatus.asStateFlow()


    fun incrementCounter() {
       _incrementCounter.value = _incrementCounter.value + 1
    }

    fun clearApiStatus() {
       _apiStatus.value = FakeApiState.Initial
    }

    fun doFakeApiCall() {
       _apiStatus.value = FakeApiState.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
        delay(1500L)
        _apiStatus.value = FakeApiState.Success
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use 
 navController.navigate with navOptions? for example:
navOptions = navOptions {
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }